# error message: "Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to convert it from datetime to date dataype. Can someone answer this? Thanks.

```
select 

(case when (t0.InvType = '13') then (select (cast(DocDate as date)) from OINV 
where DocEntry = t0.DocEntry and t0.InvType = '13'))

     when t0.InvType = '18' then (select (cast(DocDate as date)) from OPCH where DocEntry = t0.DocEntry and t0.InvType = '18')
      when t0.InvType = '19' then (select (cast(DocDate as date)) from ORPC where DocEntry = t0.DocEntry and t0.InvType = '19')
      when t0.InvType = '204' then (select (cast(DocDate as date)) from ODPO where DocEntry = t0.DocEntry and t0.InvType = '204')
      when t0.InvType = '30' then (select (cast(DocDate as date)) from OJDT where TransId = t0.DocEntry and t0.InvType = '30')
      else 0
            end) as MonthQ
```

Comment: `0` is not a date and cannot be implicitly converted to one. Perhaps you should pick a different default for your `CASE` expression?

Comment: Oh! It helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says the data type `int` is incompatible with the datatype `date`. In fact, a numeric value cannot be used with any of the "new" data/time datatypes (by "new" I mean the ones introdcued with SQL Server 2008, such as `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, `date`).

`datetime` is, however, compatible but it's recommended that for new applications you make use of `datetime2` over `datetime`. If you do, however, need to convert a numeric to a `date` you'd need to first convert it to a `datetime`, or use `DATEADD`  instead.

With `datetime`, previously the date `0` represented `'1900-01-01'`. So, instead of `CONVERT(date,DocDate)` you would need to do `DATEADD(DAY, DocDate , '19000101')`.

You could, instead, use `CONVERT(date, CONVERT(datetime,DocDate))` as well, but doing 2 conversions seems silly.